# Laravel count column of related model

Tags: laravel, model, count, eloquent, relationship

I want to count the number of upvotes and downvotes from `ScripRating` for a certain `Script`.

Script.php:

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ScriptRating');
}
```

ScriptRating.php:

```
public function script()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Script');
}
```

The script_rating database table:

```
id (primary, increments)
script_id(integer)
rating(integer) <-- Can be either 1 (upvote) or -1 (downvote)
```

To retrieve a script and display the ratings:

```
$script = Script::where('title', '=', $title)->get();
{{ $script->ratings }}
```

This works fine, it returns an array: `[{"id":1,"script_id":1,"rating":1}]`. But at this point I'm stuck. How could I count the total upvotes and downvotes for a certain script?

I also have one more small question what I'm finding confusing. This does the same as the code above:

```
$script = Script::where('title', '=', $title)->with('ratings')->get();
{{ $script->ratings }}
```

What is the difference between these two methods and which one should I use?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I made three scopes:

```
public function scopeTotalRating($query, $scriptId) {
    return $query->where('script_id', $scriptId)->get()->sum('rating');
}

public function scopeThumbsUp($query, $scriptId) {
    return $query->where('script_id', $scriptId)->having('rating', '=', 1)->get()->sum('rating');
}

public function scopeThumbsDown($query, $scriptId) {
    return $query->where('script_id', $scriptId)->having('rating', '=', -1)->get()->sum('rating');
}
```

And display them as following:

```
{{ ScriptRating::thumbsUp($script->id) }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`{{ $script->ratings->count() }}`

This will display the number total ratings a script has.

However what you're interested in doing is grouping the ratings into `upvotes` and `downvotes`, so you'll need to query your relationship by a `group by` clause.

```
Script::where('title', '=', $title)->with([
    'ratings' => function($query) {
        $query->groupBy('rating');
    })
])->get();
```

I believe the collection returned should be now grouped by `1` and `-1`. Let me know of the results!

EDIT: You can also take a look here at the documentation on querying relationships:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

**EDIT for response:**

The simplest way to do this without using group by would be separate queries:

```
$script = Script::where('title', $title)->first();

if ($script) {
    $upvotes = ScriptRating::where('script_id', $script->id)->having('rating', '>', 0)->get()->count();

    $downvotes = ScriptRating::where('script_id', $script->id)->having('rating', '<', 0)->get()->count();
}
```

Also the difference between your scripts mentioned is called `eager loading` or `lazy loading`. When you specify `->with()` in your query, this is called eager loading. If you don't do this, the query will be ran when you specify `$script->ratings`

More about eager/lazy loading here:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

**Edit for another response:**

You would use the `->whereHas('ratings')` function if you want to gather scripts that **only** have ratings. You can also check the existence of the script having ratings by doing an if statement:

```
if ($script->ratings->count() > 0) { 
    // The script has ratings
} else {
    // The script does not have ratings
}
```

If you don't want to keep repeating this code you could always put a function inside your `Script.php` model by using the following:

```
public function hasRatings()
{
    return $this->ratings->count() > 0;
}
```

Then you can do:

`if ($script->hasRatings())`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the above code but I can't figure out how to use it. How do I retrieve the down/upvotes? Also, do you know the answer to my second question?

Comment: Thanks! You can see in my first post what I made of it. The only problem I'm having now is this error: `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string` This occurs when a script doesn't have any ratings. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the `Script` model class those 2 functions:

```
public function ratingsSumRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('ScriptRating')->selectRaw('script_id, sum(rating) as sum_all')
        ->groupBy('script_id');
}

public function getRatingSumAttribute()
{

    return $this->ratingsSumRelation ?
        $this->ratingsSumRelation->sum_all: 0;
}
```

and now display sum using:

```
{{ $script->rating_sum }}
```

Comment: I did exactly that but it gives me SQL syntax errors. Also, if I understand this right, this returns the total sum of the down and upvotes. I need this data, but I also need the upvotes and downvotes individually. Excuse me if my English is lacky.

Comment: @JasonK There was a typo. Look now, if you have error, you should always provide full error message

Comment: Yes I already noticed the 't' missing. Syntax error: `near '*) as sum from script_rating where script_rating.script_id = ? group by ' at line 1 (SQL: select script_id, sum(*) as sum from script_rating where script_rating.script_id = 1 group by script_id limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel\app\views\script.blade.php)`

Comment: @JasonK I've changed the answer - changed `as `sum`` into `as sum_all` and the same in second function

Comment: Still get a syntax error: *) as sum_all from `script_rating` where `script_rating`.`script_id` = ? group b' at line 1 (SQL: select script_id, sum(*) as sum_all from `script_rating` where `script_rating`.`script_id` = 1 group by `script_id` limit 1

Comment: Thanks it works. I'm going to use the answer given by Steve, upvoted yours too.